# The position of an element on a periodic sound wave

Tags: waves, acoustics

So I am looking at the equation used to locate of a small element relative to its equilibrium position on a periodic sound wave. The equation is defined as below:

$s(x, t) = A\cos(kx - wt)$

Now I understand why the use of a sinusoidal function, but the equation is expressed in terms of a Cosine and why not simply use a sin function? Is it just a convention or there is more?

Answer (score 1):

It is a convention with some "method to its madness".

We often use complex notation for waves:

$$y = A e^{i(kx - \omega t)}\tag1$$

Now we know that

$$e^{i\theta} = \cos\theta + i\sin\theta$$

So it follows that the real part of (1) is a cosine function...

Comment: That helps but why do we use complex notation for sound waves?

Comment: The advantage of complex notation is that if you have some linear attenuation, you just add an imaginary component to the wave number... similarly, calculating velocity and acceleration become very easy. It takes some getting used to - and then you never go back to "the old way".

Answer (score 0):

The general equation for the displacement could be

$$s(x, t) = A\cos(kx - wt)+B\sin(kx-wt)$$

It appears that the author has made a choice that $s(0,0) =A$ and $B=0$ which results in  $s(x, t) = A\cos(kx - wt)$.

Others might have chosen $s(0,0) =0$ and $A=0$ which results in  $s(x, t) = B\sin(kx - wt)$.

---

Another possibility is that a sound wave can be described in terms of a variation of pressure relative to atmospheric pressure (pressure wave) or a variation of position relative to an equilibrium position (displacement wave).
There is a $90^\circ$ phase difference between the pressure wave and the displacement wave and so the author might favour the pressure wave as a sine function which would result in the displacement wave being a cosine function.

Comment: Ok, so where is the general equation derived from? I mean how can I make it sense it intuitively? Your consideration about the pressure is right, the author does make that assumption.

Comment: The equation is the solution to the one dimensional wave equation for a wave travelling in the positive x direction. There are very many references you could look at on the Internet.  Here is one, http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_47.html